# Our purpose on hashing

Tags: hash

Isn't our purpose randomness when using hashing functions? So why don't we use `rand()` function instead of doing operations on elements(like `hashVal = 37*hashVal + key[i]`)?

Comment: Because hashing has *nothing* to do with randomness. In fact, it's quite the opposite. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: A Hash is a condensed representation of a value, i.e. a hash of 1024 char string is a 4 byte integer (sizes used just for example) that depends on every char. Of course HASH does not guarantee uniqueness but it is the very opposite of random. Great minds spent great deal of time thinking of how to squeeze the maximum information in the minimum size of a hash. Think of hashes as CHECKSUMS or CRC. It is a small chunk of data dependent on a bigger chunk used for transmission quality control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  It depends on what one means by *random.*

A hash maps keys to arbitrary values -- ideally to values among which no pattern is apparent.  For example:

```
'A' => 15
'B' => 97
'C' => 43
'D' => 60
'E' => 41
```

However, a hash always maps the same key to the same value.  Hence:

```
"BED"  => [97 41 60]
"BEDE" => [97 41 60 41]
```

Every time you give the hash an `'E'`, it always hashes it as `41`, never as another value.

**Additional note**

Significant though secondary to the present discussion is that hashes need not afford unique values.  For example, this is possible:

```
'F' => 41
```

Thus, given the hashed value `41`, one cannot say whether the key was `'E'` or `'F'`.

(All this naturally suggests the question:  "Fine.  But what are hashes *for?*"  That however would be another question for another time, not the question the OP has asked.)

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't our purpose randomness when using hashing functions?

No. Technically, our purpose when using hashing functions is to map a large data set of values called keys, to a set of values called hashes. A hash function may not be *unique*, that is, more than one key may map to the same hash. However, it must *always* map a particular key to the same hash.

For example, if hash("Hello, world") = 5, then it must always be 5, no matter how many times you hash the string. Therefore using rand() in the way you are suggesting won't work, because it would map the same key to different hashes each time.

A good hash function, however, does try to map its keys to a random hash, *probabilistically*. This is not the same thing as a random number. What it means, is that on an average, each hash has roughly equal number of pre-hashes. Each key, however, is *still* mapped to its own hash, every time.

thb's answer also illustrates this.

Answer (score 1):

hash function uses for mapping not for randomness number. So we can't use random function where hash uses. A hash value is always unique on a given input.
The main goal of Hash functions is to accelerate table lookup or data comparison tasks.

**Difference:**

`key = hash(A valid input)`, key is deterministic output

`num   = random(A valid input)`, num is undetermined output

Answer (score 0):

There are similarities between random functions and hash functions, both have a determined seed and return a value.

Hashing is returning a number based upon the object's data. So yes, it does usually provide a very large number but that number is based upon the object itself.

An identical object with the same data, depending on the hash function, will return an identical value. Because of this, hashing is not ideal for returning unique numbers as far as 'randomness' is concerned.